# is 「合否の結果」 redundant?

Tags: words

> `(1)` **合否{ごうひ}の結果**は書面{しょめん}で連絡{れんらく}する。
>   `(2)` **合否**は書面で連絡する。

#1 was given as an example.

1. What is it about #1 that makes it not be redundant? Would a native really say `合否の結果`?
2. Is #2 correct Japanese?
3. How do the meanings of #1 and #2 differ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `合否の結果` is redundant, but most Japaneses don't care about it. Natives use both of the sentences(I'm a native). Those are correct and totally the same in meaning.

Comment: We also often say 「合否結果」 without using a 「の」.